# Apache cassandra Connection refused

Tags: cassandra, digital-ocean, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I've tried every single combination of configuration for apache cassandra and I am not able to get it running. Every single time I am getting nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on DigitalOcean.

I've set the listen_address to my public ip, I've set the broadcast_rpc_address to my public ip.. I've uncommented the JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname= line and added my public ip there. I've tried setting thr LOCAL_JMX variable = no in the cassandra-env.sh file.

I have allowed ports 22, 7000, 7001, 7199, 9042, 9160, 9142 in my firewall.

I have no idea what to try anymore. I've even tried to set the rpc_address to my public ip.

I've tried telling nodetool to point on the correct addres with sudo nodetool -h XX.XXX.XXX.XX status.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after a lot of time, I've discovered the problem. Buy droplets with more ram.

It turned out that you cannot run apache cassandra on a server with 512mb ram.I've expanded the ram to 1GB and it started working, immediately.

Comment: the minimum recommended size is 8gb. with 1gb you may be able to run it but unless you tune it pretty tightly it will be pretty easy to cause OOMs

Comment: Yes, I understand. Even with 1gb it crashes very often. The thing is, I only need this droplet for testing purposes, so it's okay for now. Thank you.